# Why does the same number keep repeat twice when I try to move the variables in a array?

Tags: java

Give an algorithm that rotates the elements of  an array by one position, moving the initial element to the end  of the array, as shown at right.

{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13} -> {3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 2}

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArrayQuestion {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] array = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13};

    array[array.length - 1] = array[0] ;
    for (int index = 0; index <= array.length - 2; index++) {
        array[index] = array[index + 1];
    }

   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));

}
}
```

I'm not getting any error messages but when I run the code it prints {3, 5, 7, 11, 2, 2}, Why does it print out two 2's and delete the 13?

Comment: An array doesn't have any circular functionality, you need to handle that yourself. Just like when two variables are swapped. What I am saying is that when you move everything one step to the right, the last element will get lost.

Comment: You need a buffer for one value, otherwise you are overwriting the value you want to copy at a later time. Now you have replaced the value "13" with "2" in your first step and now the value "13" is gone.

Comment: You should consider to ask nicely for Help instead of demanding something. We want a friendly community that benefits everyone.

Comment: I apologize, I didn't mean to come across that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because the first thing you do is to overwrite the element at position `array.length - 1`. You could use a temporary variable to save the element at position 0 and set the last element to that element after your loop terminates, like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] array = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13};

    int tmp = array[0];
    for (int index = 0; index <= array.length - 2; index++) {
        array[index] = array[index + 1];
    }
    array[array.length - 1] = tmp;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

**Output:**

```
[3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 2]
```

By the way, by using a loop you are doing a manual array copy which can be replaced by a call to `System.arraycopy`:

```
System.arraycopy(array, 1, array, 0, array.length - 2 + 1);
```